# openCV: can't detect shapes properly using findContours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a program where I should detect shapes - circles, squares and traingles- and color each type with different color.

I'm using `cv2.findCountours` and then `cv2.approxPolyDP` to detect each shape.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.03 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
    print len(approx)
    if len(approx)==3:
        print "triangle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(122,212,78),-1)
    elif len(approx)==4:
        print "square"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(94,234,255),-1)
    elif len(approx) == 8:
        k = cv2.isContourConvex(approx)
        if k:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (220, 152, 91), -1)


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It does detect the shapes I mentioned, but it detects as well shapes which are not circle/triangle/square and presents them as they were.

This is the image I used:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feKcS.jpg)

The output: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7j7D.jpg)

Any suggestions how to solve this problems?
Which examinations can I add?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you modified your code as my suggest if convexity check solves your problem please close previous question. For answer :

Use different epsilon values for different shapes. The epsilon value is 0.03 in your code

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.03 *   cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
```

But it may change by resolution and area of contours so you should try different epsilon values for different shapes